How to identify and extract an image from a magazin page?
I have the challenge to scan pages from 100-year-old magazines and making them accessible to a wider audience. I have to extract the texts (a typical OCR task) and separate out the images and save them in separate files.
I am using C# and Tesseract to extract texts - that's pretty easy and works (almost) perfect. I'll leave that for the time being...
Now I want to automatically extract the images - and am struggling.
Currently I am using C# and AForge.net to apply filters and operators, but none of them have produced any tangible results.
I figured that one of the challenges I face is the fact, that pictures are using some dithering (or similar algorithm) to emulate gray scales (as it was used in the beginning of then 1900ths). Hence converting the scanned image into gray scale does only reduce the pixel format (from 32bit of the scanned jpeg, into 8bit to represent grays). I tried other things like enhancing contrast and/or brightness, binarization to separate foreground from background, but the results were all the same: gazillions of individual pixels... but not a single segment, that can be extracted as an image.
Here's an example of such a page:

I hope, someone has some clever hints for me.

What is the main goal of separating the images instead of just storing the full page? Reducing storage requirements? De-dithering? Something else?

Images (as in Fotos) tend to have significantly different frequency signatures than text... If you look at this page, you'll have a lot of (near-) 0s and probably areas with a band of frequencies typical for text and the rest should be your image, at least roughly.

What you also could do is using the OCR-Data to enhance your algorithms. The OCR Systems I used to work with gave positions of the Text found. So that should give you a pretty good measure, where there is no Foto.

And last but not least, you could "reverse-engineer". There are certain "rules" that are applied in typesetting. So at least - and especially if your sources have been professionally typeset - that can further enhace your algorithms (in that certain positions, size-relations etc are more probable than others).

BTW: "Monnem vonne!" ;D - If the content is indicative of your location, I'd try to find out if the local University still has CS-Departments (which they certainly did some 20 years ago). Because this sounds like a pretty good subject for a coop.

you might want to ditch tesseract, and all custom programming, and instead just buy a commercial program to do this. that's a lot more cost-effective than spending time reinventing the wheel. -- if you must NIH, learn more about "document layout analysis" -- nobody needs to dissect the entire page. just keep the scan, and "underlay" the text, so it's selectable and copyable. that is what most OCR engines (including Adobe Acrobat) do.

any local CS department will also just send you away and tell you to just buy commercial software. OCR is a solved (academic) problem. they handed that off to industry as an "engineering" problem, i.e. for others to make good products out of it.

I would recommend Adobe Acrobat for the OCR. it did very well in everything I threw at it so far, and it is (or used to be) solid software, didn't glitch around and feel janky like competitors. it can produce editable documents but don't expect too much from that (it doesn't try to guess the style, it just maintains the scan or produces authentic-looking vector text). competitors produce editable documents too. their results are "more" editable, and they try to guess font style, but they suck at guessing the styles, so your result won't look like the original, even if you don't touch it.

for preservation, your goal should be to scan in good quality, then keep and present/distribute the scan data, but not mess with it. augment with text underlay for searchability/copy-paste/screen reader support. -- you might wanna ditch CS depts, but do ask Germanistik or history departments, maybe even the library. they'll know how to do preservation of historical documents.

dithering: avoid moire patterns, i.e. aliasing of those high frequency features. you should scan in high resolution. that also makes OCR easier. if that's too much data, you can always downsample that later, but be mindful of how downsampling is supposed to be done (first a lowpass, then decimation). many programs and libraries don't care about that, or expect you to do of the lowpass step explicitly.

As written, OCR is not the issue - I am happy with the results. Giving this to a pro company isn't an option due to costs... well, and I like these kind of challenges.

Well, it's not going to earn s.o. their phd but we did that kind of stuff for lab courses, for example.

of course, if you take it as a challenge, rather than a task, that's different. -- I didn't mean to suggest throwing $100,000 at a company to reimplement the document layout analysis. I am saying to buy an off-the-shelf program that is easy to use and already solves all the issues. that will cost something like 50-500 EUR (guessing the range), or a monthly subscription (Acrobat) that would be very cheap if you do the scanning upfront and then run the scans through the program. compared to what you, a fulltime engineer, cost per hour, that money is worth one of your work days.

What do you mean by "automatic"? I do image editing, but allow my app to accept hints (i.e. pointer presses) to identify an area of interest (e.g. sampling). The images have a higher "pixel density" than the text and "empty space" around it. "Sampling" the mostly "pure" empty space lets you identify the obvious "block" that is the image (once you eliminate the identified text "block") by scanning the pixel rows for "accepted" and rejected pixels. After a few scans, you'll have identified a "width" of the image by the exclusion of the "rejected" ("empty") pixels on either side; and so forth.

if you want to DIY, look into AI for this. AI just solves a lot of problems... or turns them into "training". -- for traditional DIY implementation of background segmentation I would try a histogram to find the big peak of "white", then a mask of that, then morphology using vertical and horizontal bars, and a combination of those. that ought to give you blocks of text and pictures, unless the pictures actually contain "white". the rest is finding connected components.
